# heroku login error

Tags: heroku

I am using Ubuntu. When I try to login to Heroku from command shell i get the follwing error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
```

Comment: when you what? post what you are doing

Comment: i tried to login to my account . after i enter my mail id and password i get the following error

Answer (score 2):

“Name or service not known” generally means that the host that you're trying to connect to is not resolving to an IP address (i.e. the DNS lookup is failing).

You can try a few troubleshooting steps:

1. **Make sure you have a connection to the internet**. Try using `ping -c10 8.8.8.8` (since you're pinging an IP address rather than a host name it should work without DNS). You get some statistics at the end of the output, if it says something along the lines of `0% packet loss` then you have an internet connection.
2. **See if DNS is working**. Try using `dig heroku.com`. You should get some output which includes an `ANSWER SECTION` listing several IP addresses.  If you get a timeout instead, then the problem is your DNS server.
3. **Try another DNS server** using `dig @8.8.8.8 heroku.com`.  If that works you should change your DNS servers (at least temporarily) to Google's `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

See also:

- [The `dig` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)
- [The `ping` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)
- [Google's instructions on changing your DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Comment: thank you, i changed the dns server to googles 8.8.8.8 and it worked